# Read value of SessionStorage when landing page gets opened

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I want to start Chrome. Open our website and read value from Session Storage. However, it seems window.sesionStorage is not the solution. I want to read value of language from sessionStorage of my web site. Note - I do not want to set sessionStorage. I want to read values set when landing page gets opened.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

run().then(() => console.log('Done')).catch(error => console.log(error));

async function run() {
  // Create a new browser. By default, the browser is headless,
  // which means it runs in the background and doesn't appear on
  // the screen. Setting `headless: false` opens up a browser
  // window so you can watch what happens.
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

  // Open a new page and navigate to google.com
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://mywebsitelanding.com/landing');

  // Wait 5 seconds
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));

const sessionStorage = await page.evaluate(() =>  window.sessionStorage)
console.log(window.sessionStorage)


  // const returnedCookie = await page.cookies();
  // console.log(returnedCookie)

  // Close the browser and exit the script
  await browser.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no window object in puppeteer:

```
const sessionStorage = await page.evaluate(() =>  window.sessionStorage)
console.log(sessionStorage)
```